# Trouble with google chrome on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

I recently tried to import some root certificate and installed some cert manager. I also gave the Chrome Beta a short try.

Since then, I have to following problems with Google Chrome:

- The unity dash consistently lists Google Chrome as "LinuxCertManagement"
- When clicking a link in any application a new empty browser window is opened. In the console I get the error message:

  > [5091:5091:0603/210149:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(1289)] Not implemented reached in void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::MapWindow(ui::WindowShowState)
- After starting chrome I get a lot of errors in the console:

  > [5091:5091:0603/205600:ERROR:nss_util.cc(853)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
  >   ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
  >   [5091:5091:0603/205600:ERROR:component_loader.cc(138)] Failed to parse extension manifest.
  >   [5091:5091:0603/205600:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(1289)] Not implemented reached in void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::MapWindow(ui::WindowShowState)
  >   [5091:5091:0603/205601:ERROR:profile_sync_service.cc(1270)] History Delete Directives datatype error was encountered: Delete directives not supported with encryption.
  >   [5091:5221:0603/205603:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(214)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
  >   [WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED

I tried running KDE but the problems stayed so it's not just a unity thing.

Can anybody help me out? I removed (purged) Chrome from my system and reinstalled it after moving away the respective directories .cache and .config. After reinstalling it the problems stayed.

When using Firefox as default browser links are opened just fine.

Comment: Firefox uses its own cert store thats the reason it worked.  The problem is the certs you imported.

Comment: @Ramhound Any quick fix you may offer? Reinstalling ca-certificates did not help.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the first problem: Deleting ~/.pki did the trick. Seems like I botched installing a certificate using certutil.